# Vue CLI 3 service worker fails to register out of box

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, service-worker, amazon-cloudfront, progressive-web-apps

I built my app using Vue CLI3 with PWA. When I build for production the service worker fails to register.

I then decided to check if it was something I did or Vue CLI 3 out the box. I built a brand new app, built it and deployed it to AWS s3 with cloudfront. Even the brand new app without any changes fails to register the service worker with error: **"The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain')."** and **"Error during service worker registration: DOMException"**

I've tried quite a few things other than listed below that google search results suggested but I end up with the same error.

I tried using the **vue.config.js** to load a custom worker in which I just copied the contents of the one that vue produces in a build.

```
pwa: {
  workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
  workboxOptions: {
    swSrc: 'public/service-worker.js'
  },
  themeColor: '#ffffff'
  }
```

I have tried loading it from `index.html` also.

**If I host it locally it registers without any issues**

The file does get created and it's accessible from the console but for some odd reason unknown to me it does not want to register at all.

Has anyone had this problem before and how did you resolve this?

Hosted on AWS s3 & cloudfront with HTTPS enabled and using the default AWS certificates for testing.

```
$ vue --version
3.9.3

$ node --version
v12.7.0

$ npm --version
6.10.0
```

#### UPDATE

I found that when I upload to S3 using aws cli sync it changes all `.js` files `content-type`

Once I resolve this I will update my question again.